# node.js inserting row multiple times sql

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I have this function:
app.post('/addProgressReport', (req, res) => {

```
       var report = req.body.url;
       var parentId = "";

        var studentName = req.body.studentName;

        console.log("62: " + studentName)
        console.log("63: " + report)
       
        var viewStudents = "select * from reportsfor where CHILDNAME = '" + studentName + "'";
        ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnMaster, function(err, conn) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            conn.query(viewStudents, function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

                //just insert new rows dynamically under report1!!!
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log(rows.length)
                    if (rows[i]["REPORT1"] === "" || rows[i]["REPORT1"] === null || rows[i]["REPORT1"] === undefined ||  rows[i]["REPORT1"] === "undefined" ||  rows[i]["REPORT1"] === " ") {
                        console.log('THIS IS AN EMPTY ROW')
                        console.log(": row is : " + rows[i]["REPORT1"])
                        updateReport1ColumnSoItIsNotAnEmptyRow(req, res, report, parentId, studentName)
                    } else {
                        console.log(rows.length)
                        console.log("80: INSERT INTO REPORTS TABLE FOR REPORT")
                        insertIntoReportsTableForAnotherReport (res, report, parentId, studentName)
                    }
                    console.log(parentId)
                }

                conn.close(function() {
                    console.log("closed the function /viewStudents");
                });
            });
        });
    })
```

which is all good. basically, some background knowledge, i am able to upload reports to my db. but then, when I upload the 3rd document, the whole app crashes. I have no clue why. This happens:

```
_http_outgoing.js:558
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

onlt on the third one, then everyone after that. I have no clue why, the code seems flawless to me!! any ideas?

Comment: for anyone who's wondering, problme was, i was inserting based on the number of rows inside the table. This requires there to be a loop, whcih means that it would automatically loop through the amount of rows and insert it as many rows as there is

Comment: I would highly suggest adjusting your code to use promises, your main issues are in the `updateReport1ColumnSoItIsNotAnEmptyRow` and `insertIntoReportsTableForAnotherReport` functions. Essentially what is happening, the request is completing before your database calls are done

Comment: please include the two other functions - you shouldnt be responding from within the loop, thats where the error is